# Is there a way to load the constant values stored in a header file via ctypes?

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm doing a bunch of ctypes calls to the underlying OS libraries. My progress slows to a crawl anytime the docs reference a constant value stored in a `.h`. file somewhere, as I have to go track it down, and figure out what the actual value is so that I can pass it into the function.

Is there any way to load a `.h` file with ctypes and get access to all of the constants?

Comment: I was looking for the same kind of functionality and if checking `.h` files is the only way, `grep` and `man` pages

Comment: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Tools/scripts/h2py.py - code in the Cpython repo to translate a .h file into some python code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

Early versions of `ctypes` came with a module called `codegenerator`, which would parse header files, both to get the constant values and to convert the prototypes into `restype`/`argtypes` declarations. However, as far as I know, this was never finished, and it was dropped from the package before inclusion in the stdlib.

You could dig into [the source](http://svn.python.org/projects/ctypes/trunk/ctypeslib/ctypeslib/codegen/) and pull out the constants stuff while skipping the much more complicated prototypes stuff.

---

However, the way I've usually done it is to write my own generator.

For example, run this script as part of your setup process:

```
constants = {}
with open('foo.h') as infile:
    for name, value in re.findall(r'#define\s+(\w+)\s+(.*)', infile):
        try:
            constants[name] = ast.literal_eval(value)
        except Exception as e:
            pass # maybe log something
with open('_foo_h.py', w) as outfile:
    outfile.write(repr(constants))
```

Then `foo.py` can just `from _foo_h import *`.

Writing a perfect regexp for this is very hard, maybe impossible; writing one that works for the headers you actually care about in a given project is very easy. In fact, often, either the one above, or one that skips over comments, is all you need.

But sometimes this won't work. For example, a header file might `#define FOO_SIZE 8` for 64-bit builds, and `#define FOO_SIZE 4` for 32-bit builds. How do you handle that?

For that, you ask the compiler to do it for you. Most compilers have a way to preprocess a file just far enough to get all of the active definitions. Some compilers can even just dump the macro defines, in a nice format, skipping everything else. With `gcc` and flag-compatible compilers like `clang`, `-E` preprocesses, and `-dM` dumps macros. So:

```
macros = subprocess.check_output(['gcc', '-dM', '-E', '-', 'foo.h'])
for line in macros.splitlines():
    try:
        _, name, value = line.split(None, 2)
        constants[name] = ast.literal_eval(value)
    except Exception as e:
        pass # again, do something nicer
```

You may want to pass in some extra compiler flags to control what gets defined appropriately, like the results of `pkgconfig foo --cflags`.

This will also give you the macros defined in anything that `foo.h` (recursively) includes, and gcc's builtin macros. You may or may not want each of those. Somewhere among [the 69105 gcc flags](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html), I believe there are ways to control that, but I don't remember them.

---

Note that neither of these will get you constant variables or enums, like:

```
static const int SPAM_SPAM_SPAM = 73;
enum {
    kSPAM = 1,
    kEGGS
};
```

Parsing that gets more difficult; you'd want to use a real C99 parser like [`pycparser`](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser)—or, alternatively, you'd want to parse the output of something like `gccxml` instead of `gcc -E`. But even that isn't going to tell you that `kEGGS` is 2 without you writing a bit of logic.

And if you want to deal with C++, it's even worse, what with constexpr and static class members and user-defined literals…

---

Alternatively… do you have to use `ctypes`?

[`CFFI`](http://cffi.readthedocs.org/en/release-0.7/) provides a different way to call C code from Python—and it makes this a lot easier.

[`Cython`](http://www.cython.org) lets you write almost-Python code that gets compiled to C that gets compiled to a Python extension module, and it can include header files directly.

There are also a variety of binding-generators (e.g., SWIG) or binding-writing libraries (e.g., boost::python) that can make it easier to export values to Python through an extension module.

Comment: @eryksun: +1 on suggesting CFFI. I'm not sure it's necessary to give details unless the OP asks for it.

Comment: Hi, just wanted to know if it's still the case, and there's no native way to import C enumerator or any other constants that we usually see in header file, to python